# Get all results from the customer table. Replace null values in the state and fax columns with an empty string. How to solve this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, coalesce

I am very confused about this question .The thing is know that I can use COALESCE function for this but how ?Because there are 2 columns here ,State and Fax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if null

```
select id,ifnull(state, '') as state ,ifnull(fax, '') as fax from customer
```

Comment: Yeah ,Thanks alot ,It really worked!